# Bad position of div

Tags: html, css, dom

I have div inside which I want to have other divs, each one 10 px under the previous one. My css code of it is

```
.item{
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    height: 80px;
    border: dashed 2px black;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

but it places every div in the same place(10px under top of parent div). How can I do it?

Additionaly I want to have a slider, when there is not enough place to contain all of divs.

Comment: Please add the html code and rewrite the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set to position: relative :)

```css
.item{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    height: 80px;
    border: dashed 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now it's in a good order but it leaves parent's right side. How can I fix it?

Comment: With     margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;  ?

Comment: Now it's great. I just have one more question. Look at that https://gyazo.com/97a848e00d2388cb33b51005b44f80c8 . These ittle divs leave parent div and I want to have slider on the right side if there is not enough space for them.

Comment: Give the parent div -> overflow: scroll;    And what do you mean with slider to the right?